# How to get current cursor position in Lightning:inputrichtext field?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning, javascript-controller, inputrichtext

How do I get the current cursor position in a lightning:inputrichtext field?

Say an event is triggered and I want to insert text at the cursor. What does the js look like?

Comment: Can you please show the code, what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is not possible because you need to get hold of the cursor position of the `lightning:inputRichText` which is not exposed either by ***attribute*** or by ***action*** as of now, also it's part of `lightning` namespace so you cannot read the DOM due to **Locker Service**.

If you are using HTML `textarea` tag (need to manually do the data binding stuffs), then you achieve the behavior as explained in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1064139/3875740)